# gridview EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks

Tags: asp.net

I put my gridview inside an updatepanel and my paging and sorting seem to be working well. If I set the property EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks = "true", it works equally well.

What does this property do? For now my app is running on my laptop but will the settings of this property matter when I deploy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks uses Ajax instead of a regular postback to implement the GridView's sorting and paging buttons. I don't know what happens when you subsequently stick the GridView into an UpdatePanel.